# Spatie Media Library (Pro) - attach auth token to `upload` call

Tags: laravel, laravel-medialibrary

I am using Spatie's Media Library (Pro), and we have an SPA that requires all the calls from the front-end to use an auth token with some "context" information.

(Our front-end is Nuxt.js/Vue.js; we send the calls to a micros-service gateway, but that's not really part of the issue here, only explaining why we can't do the "normal" way  )

When I use the MediaLibraryAttachment or MediaLibraryCollection, dragging a new file to the dropzone fires the `/upload` call...but I can't attach my own token to it.

There is a `withCredentials` prop on those components, but they seem to only generate cookies.

Googling for a couple of days gives me zero hits on this, which makes me think I'm completely misunderstanding something. Does it make sense to be trying to do this, and if so, how?

---

Alternatively, loading the image but stopping the `upload` from firing would work, since I prefer to submit my own. I can stop the upload, but then it doesn't pre-load the image

Comment: Sounds like a case for a custom vue component? https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v9/handling-uploads-with-media-library-pro/creating-custom-vue-components

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
<media-library-attachment
name="avatar"
:headers="headers"
/>

const headers = {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${JWT_Token}`
};
```